# decode in oracle producing diff output

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SQL> select decode(grouping(deptno),1,'TOTAL',0,deptno) example,sum(sal) 
     from emp
     group by rollup(deptno);

example                                    SUM(SAL)
---------------------------------------- ----------
10                                             8750    
20                                             10875    
30                                             9400    
TOTAL                                          29025

 SQL> select decode(grouping(deptno),0,deptno,1,'TOTAL'), sum(sal) 
      from emp 
      group by rollup(deptno);
```

ERROR:

> ORA-01722: invalid number

case3:

```
 select (case grouping(deptno) when 1 then 'all' when 0 then deptno end) example,sum(sal) from emp group by rollup(deptno)
```

Error:Expected char got number

I'm trying the above,expecting same output but it is showing diff.

Comment: Can you show your table structure please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the DECODE manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm);

> Oracle automatically converts the return value to the same datatype as the first result.

In your first query, the first result is `TOTAL`, a string type, so the column type is a string, which `deptno` can be converted to without problems.

In your second query, the first result is `deptno`, a numeric type, so the coumn type is numeric. Since `TOTAL`, the second result, cannot be converted to a numeric type, the query fails with `ORA-01722: invalid number`.

Comment: What about this explanation on this link: [Grouping](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions064.htm#SQLRF51428) the second decode is doing exactly the same (i think, am i wrong?). I'm just asking to understand.

Comment: select (case grouping(deptno) when 1 then 'all' when 0 then deptno end) example,sum(sal) from emp group by rollup(deptno)... i have tried this..but saying expected char got number

Comment: @JorgeCampos Not sure what you mean, but the second DECODE "`DECODE(GROUPING(job_id), 1, 'All Jobs', job_id) AS job`" in the link returns `All Jobs` (a string) if the value of the grouping is 1, for all other values `job_id`. Since the first value, `All Jobs` is a string, the column type will be a string type.